# Is there a variable in VS2017 for the package id and version number? (External Tool menu item to call Nuget Push)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I'd like to add an external 'Nuget Push' command to VS2017 but the closest I can get for the `nuget` argument list is:

```
push $(ProjectDir)bin\$(Configuration)\*.nupkg -Source "xxx" -ApiKey xxx
```

(Where Source and ApiKey are our private values).

This (sort of) works, but it would be cleaner if I could specify `$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg` instead of `*.nupkg`. Do any suitable variables exist which could be used to build the exact filename?

Update:

This is in the definition of an External Tool, not a `<Target>`. With these settings:
[image]

An example result is:

```
File does not exist (C:\TFS\DefaultCollection\Forge\Forge.POCO\bin\Debug\..nupkg).
```

Comment: Do you mean you could not use the arguments `$(PackageId)` and `$(PackageVersion)`?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Exactly. I've updated the question with a screenshot of the External Tool setup and the result, which just seems to substitute empty strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't, I've opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6369) for this before, but realised there may be too few users for this to implement, since using `$(PackageId)` and `$(PackageVersion)` works I most scenarios.

A NuGet team member suggested using one of the `NuGetPackOutput` items, which contain all .nuspec and .nupkg files created:

```
<Target Name="Foo" DependsOnTargets="Pack">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="NuGetPackOutput: %(NuGetPackOutput.Identity)" Condition="'%(NuGetPackOutput.FileExtension)' == '.nupkg'" />
</Target>
```

But in most cases, using `$(PackageOutputAbsolutePath)$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg` also works.

If you find this doesn't work for you or you need a more specific property or item, do comment on the issue.

Comment: That's defining a `<Target>`, which probably works but I don't always want to attempt an upload every time I do a test Build. Although they should fail (as the version won't have been updated), I'd prefer to upload semi-manually. Ideally, the `-Source` and `-ApiKey` option values should also be obtained from somewhere in the project, but I don't think there's anywhere defined.

Comment: you'd call this target using `dotnet msbuild /t:Foo`, it doesn't run automatically.

Comment: OK. By adding a `<Target ...><Exec Command="...nuget push..." /></Target>"` section to the project file and replacing the External Tool definition with the `dotnet` invocation, I've achieved what I want, i.e. a menu command to automatically push the package to the gallery. Thanks.